# Suitable translation of "Human Becomings"

Tags: traducción, neologismos

In the field of Ontology of Process, one considers *Human Becomings* instead of *Human Beings*. The phrase in English expresses clearly the idea of the continuity of the process of being Human.

What would be a suitable translation into Spanish, one that preserves the connotation?

Comment: You might get better answers if you can provide some suggestions for people to evaluate.

Comment: Nice combination of philosophy and language.

Comment: Como sugirió @mdewey, y como señala rsanchez en su respuesta, al presente, uso "Devenires Humanos". Llegue a esta traducción por via del Francés "devenir", que conota "become" con un sentido más cercano.

Comment: @JorgeO-L - Tambien uso ese truco (chequear en frances) y funciona 90% de las veces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A usual translation seems to be *devenires humanos*. See for instance this excerpt from [*Ambientes para la vida*](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=9X_LttlDMl8C&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq=devenires%20humanos&source=bl&ots=djW4E36xbh&sig=JtIrAJs8dycVIUosZ5obKD44IRk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj02LOBm4jZAhVFh5AKHRLZCEgQ6AEIMTAB#v=onepage&q=devenires%20humanos&f=false), a Spanish translation of a series of conferences by Tim Ingold:

> Lo que somos, entonces, o lo que podemos ser, no viene ya hecho. Tenemos que, perpetuamente e interminablemente, estar haciéndonos. O en una palabra, los humanos no son *seres* sino *devenires*, cada uno instanciado como una cierta forma de vida en el mundo [...] En consecuencia, los devenires humanos 
>   continuamente forjan sus caminos, y guían los caminos de sus compañeros, en el crisol de su vida en común.

Comment: Me gustó. Bastante en línea con lo que dice el DRAE: http://dle.rae.es/?id=DbbMdRW|DbcjgjX, sólo que el diccionario habla del proceso en sí, no del humano en ciernes o en proceso.

Comment: Ah!! Muchísimas gracias @rsanchez por esta cita. Tendré que buscar referencias al traductor de Ingold, porque este párrafo señala precisamente el sentido en el que yo uso la expresión en mi trabajo presente.

Answer (score 1):

Traducir `not simply human **beings**, but human becomings` no tiene tanto problema

> no (somos) simplemente seres humanos, si no que nos **convertimos** en humanos

Tenemos el verbo [humanizar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KnbmIsL)

> Hacer humano, familiar y afable a alguien o algo.

(o [humanar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KnPRZ5a%7CKncKsrP))

> 1. tr. p. us. **Hacer a alguien humano**, familiar y afable. U. m. c. prnl.

Por lo que podrías intentar traducir "human becomings" por "seres humanados o humanizados". Personalmente prefiero `humanando`, por esa connotación de "hacer **a alguien** humano", aunque ese alguien sea uno mismo.

Si le quieres dar la misma sensación de "continuidad" puedes usar "humanándose" o "humanizándose".

Comment: ¿Podríamos ser los *humanizandos*, entonces?

Comment: Buena propuesta, Pablo. En analogía con *los educandos*.

Answer (score 1):

Por mantener un poco la sonoridad de "ser", y el sentido de que el humano no "es", sino que "se va haciendo", *podrías* usar "hacer".

El "[ser](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Xe5NPsQ)" de "ser humano" no es el verbo "[ser](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Xe5Brrm)", sino un sustantivo derivado del mismo: justo como pasa en inglés con "*[being](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/being)*".

El verbo "[hacer](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Jwhmcap)" no tiene en español tal forma de sustantivo (aunque hay algunos rastros, como el sustantivo "[quehacer](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UlraVzO)"), pero eh, tampoco la tiene "*[becoming](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/becoming)*" en inglés, así que la relación es la misma que entre "ser" y "*being*".

Por tanto, si a *human beings* (adjetivo "humano" + sustantivo reconocido *beings* significando "ser, son") le corresponde  "seres humanos", a *human becomings* (adjetivo "humanos" + sustantivo inventado *becomings* significando "hacerse, se hacen") le podría corresponder "**haceres humanos**".

Comment: *haceres* suena a tareas o actividades. ¿Qué tal *los haciéndose humanos*?

Comment: Sí, precisamente; la carencia de un sustantivo equivalente a "Becoming" es el reto. Gracias @walen!